# Is DataAdapter a reliable way to Insert data into an SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataadapter

Yesterday My colleague told me that using data adapter to insert data into an sql server database is not reliable, because it does not guarantee that data are inserted properly. He also told me that if the data insertion is unsuccessful, it does not show any kind of error message.

I am really confused. I thought microsoft invented ado.net so that data can be inserted into the database without any extra hazard.

What do you guys think? Is data adapter unreliable?

Comment: ask your colleague for FACTS and PROOF - I've never heard this. DataAdapter is one of the known, often used ways of doing this. If you get your SQL statements right and don't violate any DB constraints, I don't see why he would claim this to be "unreliable". Most likely, it's not the DataAdapter, but the programmer using it, how's got something wrong... (a classic case of PICNIC: Problem in Chair, **NOT** In Computer)

Comment: thank you mark. The adapter we are talking about is used to insert an order from a web page. Now, I have tested into local pc, and it is working fine. But whenever some client of the site is inserting order, he told me that sometimes it is being inserted, sometimes it is not. Even if there is some problem in the sql statement, it is supposed to throw an exception, isn't it? But there is no exception message about it. I wonder what is really wrong here

Comment: Even though I'm not a *huge* fan of `DataAdapter`, I agree with @marc_s - it is for your colleague to explain his position.

Comment: Archangel: If there is a problen in the sql statement you'll get an exception for sure.
"I wonder what is really wrong here". what is really wrong here is your colleague :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataAdapter is just as reliable as using a SqlCommand directly (ie: reliable enough).

It may not be the fanciest way to do this but it has been around for about as long as .NET itself and it is used by very many applications.